# interval +variable PostgreSql

Tags: postgresql, datetime, timestamp, procedure, postgresql-9.3

is there anyone at there who knows how to use a variable interval  instead of a number interval in postgresql?

For example :

Comment: This loop really looks strange. What are you trying to do there? More often than not, a "LOOP" approach is the worst solution you can use. Also: the `SELECT p1_per_rot into nbmois FROM opt_par` is dangerous as you are not using an WHERE clause to limit the number or rows from `opt_par`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `make_interval()`

```
make_interval(days => 1, months => nbmois);
```